# CSV readinf TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, csv

Python Newbie here. I keep getting this error when trying to sort a csv list

I have the code to write into the csv file that works ok in that it writes the name and the three scores e.g.  John, 3,2,2,

```
    f = open('test.csv', "a")  
    try:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow( (name, myScore, myScore2, myScore3) )
        print("Your entries have been added")
    finally:
        f.close()
```

But I want to read from the CSV and sort the output

```
        sample = open('test.csv','r')
        test1 = csv.reader(sample,delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        sort = sorted(test, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
        for row in sort:
             print (row)
```

Tried itemgetter(1)), 2,3 etc.. same Int Object is not iterable error?
I am obviously missing something obvious (not to me!) but can someone help me work it out.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to use `test` or `test1` there?

Comment: You can also simply rewrite your sort as ``sorted(test, key = lambda row: row[0])``, much, *much* clearer as to what you're trying to do. Though keep in mind that CSV returns strings, not numbers, and sorting string-numbers is *not* going to do what you want (``111`` will come before `3`). If you know the row is going to be a number, you should do ``sorted(test, key = lambda row: int(row[0]))`` (or float if appropriate)

Comment: Hi I tried sorted(test, key = lambda row: int(row[0])) but keep getting this errorTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\A453_Task3_quiz.py", line 31, in <module>
    sorted(test, key = lambda column: int(column[2]))
  File "C:\Python34\A453_Task3_quiz.py", line 31, in <lambda>
    sorted(test, key = lambda column: int(column[2]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Score'